# How do I implement FormAuthentication in Signal R

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am using Signal R in my mvc 3 application. When I trying to connect from client it gets failed.

```
$.connection.hub.start(function () {
            alert('connected');
        }).fail(function () { alert('failed'); }).done(function () {
            msgserver.unreadMessagesCount("SignalR", int);
        });
```

Comment: Sorry guys!!! Actually I have referred the wrong js file. After referring the correct file its working. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You do not implement FormsAuth in SignalR. You implement FormsAuth in your MVC application

Comment: I already have FormsAuth in my MVC application. When start the hub connection its failed. Do I have maintain the FormsAuth cookie same as in hub connection? If yes how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post by Tugberk](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/mapping-asp-net-signalr-connections-to-real-application-users) has a full working example of using authentication with SignalR, as well as tips on how to map connections to app users. Try using the attached code as a base for your implementation.